# RxJS run selector function only once

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am using the combineLatest observable with two streams and selector function.

```js
const todos = Rx.Observable.of([{
  id: 1,
  completed: false,
  text: 'one'
}, {
  id: 1,
  completed: true,
  text: 'two'
}]);

const filter = Rx.Observable.of('SHOW_ALL');


const getTodos = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(todos, filter, (todos, filter) => {
  console.log('calculation');
  // doing some calculation...
  return todos;
});

getTodos.subscribe(console.log)
getTodos.subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

I need the result selector to run only once for both the subscribers to avoid recalculation. For example something like cache the result and give me the latest value if neither of the inputs changes.

There is a way to do this with RxJS?

Comment: Please take a look at `share` and `publish` operators: they're designed for such situation.

Comment: I tried the share operator it does not work for me.

Comment: @undefined I doesn't work how? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: getTodos.share()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `shareReplay` operator. It allows you to share the value produced by your `combineLatest` between all the subscribers.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md

You might want to have a look at `replay` if you don't want the automatic connect/disconnect when the subscriber go from 0 to 1 or more and vice versa.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/replay.md

```
const getTodos = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(todos, filter, (todos, filter) => {
  console.log('calculation');
  // doing some calculation...
  return todos;
})
.shareReplay();
```

Here is a running example:

```js
const todos = Rx.Observable.of([{
  id: 1,
  completed: false,
  text: 'one'
}, {
  id: 1,
  completed: true,
  text: 'two'
}]);

const filter = Rx.Observable.of('SHOW_ALL');

const getTodos = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(todos, filter, (todos, filter) => {
  console.log('calculation');
  // doing some calculation...
  return todos;
})
.shareReplay();

getTodos.subscribe(console.log.bind(console))
getTodos.subscribe(console.log.bind(console))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.lite.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Rx.Observable.combineLatest(...).shareReplay is not a function

Comment: `shareReplay` is available since RxJS 5.4.0. You most likely have older versison.

Comment: Oh really!!! No it is available in RxJS4 also (the doc I have linked is from the v4 docs)

Comment: @martin It's actually in Rx since V2.3.1 https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/v2.3.1/doc/api/core/operators/sharereplay.md I guess you are not using such an old version

Comment: here is a working example with shareReplay http://jsbin.com/cafasunife/edit?html,js,console,output As you can see, there are 2 subscribers and 2 events and only 2 `calculation` log

Comment: It should be one calculation log no twice.

Comment: This is the right operator in Rx version 5 .publishReplay(1).refCount()

Comment: @atomrc RxJS 5 is a complete rewrite of RxJS 4 and some operators were added later. If you don't trust me it takes about 30s to check it for yourself in the change log that `shareReplay()` was added on 2017-05-09 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#540-2017-05-09

Comment: @martin well I didn't know they removed `shareReplay` between v4 and v5 indeed. I knew it was a complete rewrite though :) Maybe if the question is about `rxjs5`, op should add it as a tag or in the description?

Comment: @undefined your `todo` stream emits 2 values, so you necessarily run the `combineLatest` callback twice (at least). If you only want 1 value, you might be looking for the `filter` operator, but I guess this is not what you want to do. What `shareReplay` does is that the `combineLatest` is  called only once for all the subscribers